# Potential bug in sonar detection of commented out code

Tags: java, sonarqube

In our system we use comment blocks to define system text.e.g.

```
private static final int STR_SYS_TEXT_1 = 1 /* RES_TAG Example text: {0} */;
```

The above code is flagged as commented out code where as the following does not...

```
private static final int STR_SYS_TEXT_1 = 1 /* RES_TAG Example text: {0}. */;
```

The difference is the the period after the closing curly bracket.

The current work round is to use //NOSONAR on the end of those lines that are flagged up, but I think this masks a problem in the sonar 'commented out' detection code

Comment: You should raise a bug report in the SonarQube JIRA.

Comment: or reach out to sonarqube@googlegroups.com

Comment: I registered as a user on the SonarQube JIRA but there is no option to actually create a jira there

Comment: @CJY This is on purpose we prefer to rely on google groups to discuss before opening tickets.